# Is there a way to make the bash auto-complete show a list with line for each entry?

Tags: bash, auto-completion

when I want to see the content of a dir I use `~/` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and it shows me

```
.bashrc.swp           .gitconfig            .local/   ...
```

Is there a way to make the results separated by newlines?

i.e.

```
.bashrc.swp 
.gitconfig
.local/   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bind 'set completion-display-width 0'
```

If you run this in the shell, it will affect the current session. If you want it to affect all sessions, put it at the end of your ~/.bashrc.

Or you can put this line in your ~/.inputrc:

```
set completion-display-width 0
```

Source and more details: [Grisha Levit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42215468/4518341) on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24781739/4518341)